# Powershell locking first and last files and I cannot delete them without close powershell ISE

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-ise

So I have a Powershell ISE   ( tried running as administrator and w/o )   and it is created dummy .mdf file      ,  50 of them

Problem is that it holds onto the 1st and last , so copying or deleting them is not working ...

This is my script

```
param(
$amount = 50 # $(throw "Please give an amount of files to be created")
, $size = 5 # $(throw "Please give a the size of the files")
, $folder = "C:\dev\powershell\oldlocation" # $(throw "Please give an output folder wehere the files need to be created")
, $name = 'db' # $null
, $extension = '.mdf' # $null    .mdf  / .ldf
)
CLS
# Check for input
if(Test-Path $folder)
{
if($name -eq $null)
{
Write-Host "No filename given. Using default setting 'dummy'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$name = 'dummy'
}

if($extension -eq $null)
{
Write-Host "No filename extension given. Using default setting '.txt'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$extension = 'txt'
}
elseif($extension -contains '.')
{
$extension = $extension.Substring(($extension.LastIndexOf(".") + 1), ($extension.Length - 1))
}

for($i = 1; $i -le $amount; $i++)
{
$path = $folder + '\' + $name + '_' + $i + '.' + $extension
$file = [io.file]::Create($path)
$file.SetLength($size)
$file.Close
sleep 0.5
}

}
else{
Write-Host "The folder $folder doesn't exist" -ForegroundColor Red
Exit(0)
}
```

Comment: `$file.Close` -> `$file.Close()`

Comment: Cool,   can you put as an answer quickly   that worked   thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `()` are omitted on a method, it returns the Overload Definitions. So the line where you are trying to close the file just needs `()`.

```
$file.Close()
```

If you see `OverloadDefinitions` ever returned, that's what to look for.